# Eliminating last part of url string in php

Tags: php

I have a url string like this:

```
http://example.com/sfm?dir=uploads/sfm/root/folder5/file.zip
```

`echo $_GET['extract']` outputs this: `uploads/sfm/root/folder5/file.zip` 
How can i strip the last file.zip so that

`echo $_GET['extract']` outputs this: `uploads/sfm/root/folder5/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use [dirname](http://php.net/manual/en/function.dirname.php) - Returns a parent directory's path

```
echo dirname($_GET['extract'])."/";
```

Comment: Awesome! Works great

Answer (score 3):

use below code :

```
$String = $_GET['extract'];
$Words = explode('/', $String);
echo end($Words );
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$url = "uploads/sfm/root/folder5/file.zip";
$urlArr= explode("/",$url);
array_pop($urlArr);
echo implode("/",$urlArr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this works:

```
echo substr((string)$_GET['extract'],26);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<?php

 $ss ="uploads/sfm/root/folder5/file.zip";

 $vv  = explode('/',$ss);

array_pop($vv);

$mm =implode('/',$vv);
print_r($mm);

 ?>
```